# sequelize.js deep save model instance

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

With sequelize, I am trying to update a nested attribute without success:

```
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
    title: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
    color: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
});

const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    name: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
});

Product.belongsTo(User);
User.hasMany(Product);

// create some data
await User.create({
    name: 'foo',
    products:[
        { title: 'prod1', color:'blue' },
        { title: 'prod2', color:'red' },
    ]
},
{ include: [ Product ] }
);

// query data
var data = await sequelize.models.user.findOne({
    where: { name:'foo' },
    include: [ Product ]
});

// update data
data.products[0].color = 'green';
await data.save();

// result
var data = await sequelize.models.user.findAll({
    include: [ Product ]
});
```

Here, the product color is still blue.
I wondering what is going wrong

**edit1:**
I need to update from the "root" of my model because data update come from a JSON structure, and data of included models are part of this structure

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `update` on the instance of the `product` model:

```
await data.products[0].update({
  color: 'some other color'
});
```

As it stands now, you are just changing the value of the object returned by `findOne`. When you call `save`, the instance of the model does not know that you changed any values yet.

Comment: I need to update from the "root" of my model because data update come from a JSON structure, and data of included models are part of this structure

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. In my example, you're updating the product model. Which model are you looking to update?